# Checkbox Column in ExtJS TreeGrid

Tags: javascript, gridview, treeview, extjs, checkbox

is there a way to include a checkbox column in the new extjs widget TreeGrid ? Marking the nodes attribute checked to false/true just doesn't work as it was for the TreePanel.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified Ext.ux.tree.TreeGridNodeUI class to implement this feature:
https://gist.github.com/745436

Comment: wondering if you can help me out?  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058921/configuration-required-to-get-sencha-extjs-treegrid-example-working