# ExtJs TreeGrid with editor column. Exists?

Tags: extjs, tree, grid, extjs4, treegrid

I need an ability to edit values in a grid column of a treegrid. Simply adding a editor to the column's config didn't helped. I'm using ExtJs4 treepanel component.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: try to change the 'xtype' of the column

Comment: didn't get you? how xtype allows editing?

Comment: I'm using extjs4, your link is about extjs3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, it exists.

I would recommend using the latest version, which at this time is 4.1 Release Candidate 1.

Use an Ext.Tree.Panel

add a Grid Editing plugin, like this:

```
  plugins:[
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
      clicksToEdit:2
    })
  ]
```

make at least one of the columns editable like this

```
editor:{
  xtype:'textfield'
}
```

You are basically combining this:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/tree/treegrid.html

and this:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/cell-editing.html

Answer (score 3):

found the solution:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131602-4.0.0-Cellediting-on-TreeGrid
 http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?143983-Problems-Trying-To-Edit-Tree-Panel-ExtJS-4